# HttpPostedFileBase editor for using with EditorForModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Okay, maybe I'm missing something, but I can't figure this out. Using ASP.NET MVC 3, Razor views.

I have a model object like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
    public string Title { get;set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

When, in a strongly typed view, I call @Html.EditorForModel(), it only generates the Title and Description form fields.

I created the file: Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\HttpPostedFileBase.cshtml, with dummy content, but it still doesn't get rendered.

Is it possible to get EditorForModel to generate file input fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it working by creating a custom `Object.cshtml` editor template:

```
@foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => pm.ShowForEdit && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm))) 
{
    if (prop.HideSurroundingHtml) 
    {
        @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName)
    } 
    else 
    {
        <div class="editor-container">
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label(prop.PropertyName, prop.DisplayName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName, prop.TemplateHint)
                @Html.ValidationMessage(prop.PropertyName, "*")
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Basically it calls `Html.Editor()` for each property of the model. I don't know if it's a good solution, but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

I have [investigated](http://blogs.telerik.com/atanaskorchev/posts/10-09-30/using_nested_complex_objects_with_asp_net_mvc_editor_templates.aspx) a similar problem - the editor for complex properties is not output. Your case may be different but the workaround that I found (creating an editor for your model - Model.ascx) should work for you too.

Comment: I don't want to create a view for each model that has a file input, since I'll have a few in my application.

Comment: I know that it sucks but this may be the only solution. Normally you could use UIHint but since HttpPostedFileBase is a complex type it won't be taken into account.